# in this if statement to used count how many consecutive times each distinct value appears, why doesn't it print the final value?

Tags: c++

this example from c++ primer 5th edition uses if to write a program to count how many consecutive
times each distinct value appears in the input

If we give this program the following input:

```
42 42 42 42 42 55 55 62 100 100 100
```

then the output should be

```
42 occurs 5 times
55 occurs 2 times
62 occurs 1 times
100 occurs 3 times
```

but when i try it doesn't print the last value or it's count. here is the code:

```
  #include <iostream>
  int main()
  {
       // currVal is the number we're counting; we'll read new values into val
       int currVal = 0, val = 0;
       // read first number and ensure that we have data to process
       if (std::cin >> currVal) {
          int cnt = 1; // store the count for the current value we're processing
          while (std::cin >> val) { // read the remaining numbers
              if (val == currVal) // if the values are the same
                 ++cnt; // add 1 to cnt
              else { // otherwise, print the count for the previous value
                 std::cout << currVal << " occurs "
                           << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
                 currVal = val; // remember the new value
                 cnt = 1; // reset the counter
             }
          }   // while loop ends here
           // remember to print the count for the last value in the file
          std::cout << currVal << " occurs "
                    << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
       } // outermost if statement ends here
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What did you observe when you stepped through your code line by line with the debugger? Were there any unexpected variable values? If yes, when did the value change exactly?

Comment: Are you closing stdin when you're done? The loop is going to keep running until stdin is closed. This can be done by piping in a file or using Ctrl+D on most terminal emulators on Unix-like systems. Otherwise, it's just going to hang and wait for more input

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Seems fine here: https://ideone.com/QYIKmh As @SilvioMayolo said you need to end the program by generating an EOF.

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned above you can use Ctrl+D or you can use a statement for example: If the user enters -1 the loop breaks.

### I have added the statement into your code

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    // currVal is the number we're counting; we'll read new values into val
    int currVal = 0, val = 0;
    // read first number and ensure that we have data to process
    std::cout << "-1 to exit\n";
    if (std::cin >> currVal) {
        int cnt = 1; // store the count for the current value we're processing
        while (std::cin >> val && val != -1) { // read the remaining numbers
            if (val == -1) // if the user enters -1 the loop breaks
                break;
            else if (val == currVal) // if the values are the same
                ++cnt; // add 1 to cnt
            else { // otherwise, print the count for the previous value
                std::cout << currVal << " occurs "
                    << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
                currVal = val; // remember the new value
                cnt = 1; // reset the counter
            }
        }   // while loop ends here
         // remember to print the count for the last value in the file
        std::cout << currVal << " occurs "
            << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
    } // outermost if statement ends here
    return 0;
}
```